# Null-pointer exception when invoking get in rest-assured: Cannot get property 'assertionClosure' on null object

Tags: java, rest, groovy, rest-assured

I am trying to implement tests for an RESTful API using rest-assured, but I am running into a null pointer exception when attempting to invoke a get action. The authorization is a custom scheme, so once I get the authorization signature for the request, I append it as a header to the request:

```
    String auth = ...CUSTOM ALGORITHM ...;
    String pragma = ... OTHER CUSTOM HEADER ...;

    RequestSpecification requestSpec = new RequestSpecBuilder()
       .addHeader("Authorization", auth)
       .addHeader("pragma", pragma)
       .build();

    RestAssured.baseURI = "https://blahblah.staging.somewhere.net";
    RestAssured.port = 443;
    RestAssured.basePath = "/endpoint_name/somefolder/resource?status=active";
    RestAssured.urlEncodingEnabled = false;

    requestSpec.get();
```

This results in the following error:

java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot get property 'assertionClosure' on null object

Answer (score 10):

Try using RestAssured.given() to call your GET.  You can use your requestSpec by doing something like this:

```
RestAssured.given()
.spec(requestSpec)
.log().all()
.get()
.then()
.log().all()
.statusCode(200);
```

Comment: Similar issue than OP, you solution solved it for my. Not sure why it didn't work in the first place though, seems almost like a bug in rest-assured to me.

Answer (score 1):

I encountered the same problem with RestAssured 3.0.7

It looks like that if you build `RequestSpecification` with `RequestSpecBuilder` some internal state of `RequestSpecificationImpl` is not set (`responseSpecification` field) what results with NPE when calling get/post methods.

Instead of using:

```
RequestSpecification requestSpec = new RequestSpecBuilder()
       .addHeader("Authorization", auth)
       .addHeader("pragma", pragma)
       .build();
```

use:

```
RestAssured.with().header("Authorization", auth).header("pragma", pragma)
```

`with()` is equivalent of `given` which constructs correct `RequestSpecification`

Answer (score 1):

this is a bug in rest assured

instead of

```
    requestSpec.get();
```

try:

```
Response response = RestAssured.given(requestSpec).get();
```

or

```
Response response = RestAssured.given().spec(reqSpec).get();
```

here is the already filed bug:
https://github.com/rest-assured/rest-assured/issues/938

Answer (score 0):

My co-worker finally figured out what the problem was. We use a custom authentication system for extra security and the problem had to do with a timestamp on the generated authentication header value. The timestamp was too old.

Comment: Same problem here, but definitely no timestamp issues with the authentication header. I guess there's more than one possible cause.